# Git update branch to master

Tags: git, version-control, branch, branching-and-merging

I have a `feature` branch that I work on. Yesterday I did a commit and also merged my `feature` branch into the remote `master` branch.

Now I   wish to continue working on my branch and add more functionality. However, since yesterday other people have added some additional code to the `master` branch. How can I "update" my `feature` branch so that It has all latest changes from `master`?

I could obviously just pull the latest version of `master` and simply create a new branch off of it, but I guess there is away to "update" my current `feature` branch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, there has the way to update `feature` branch based on the latest `master` branch. You just need to execute the command on `feature` branch:

```
# On feature branch
git pull origin master --rebase
```

Now the `feature` branch contains the latest changes of `master` branch.

Comment: To the person who vote down: did you try this command, and can you explain the reason?

Comment: This seems to work. Although I did it in more or less 2 stpes
First pull the master branch, then rebase my feature branch to the master.

Does the above command do both of these at once?

Comment: No, it only update the `feature` branch. To update `master` branch, you should execute `git pull origin master` on `master` branch.

Comment: This will work but seems like a bad practice, since it merge from master which better be done in several steps so it would be clear that this is what you really meant to do. Many people runs that command by mistake when on a branch and wants to pull the remote version of the branch, and instead they merge the master into their branch.

Comment: @yorammi : when you say "*pull* the remote version of the branch" do you mean "*checkout*"? Git is confusing but fetch then merge isn't less confusing than pull; people will still do it when they are actually trying to checkout.

Answer (score 2):

## Push feature branch to master

1. Change to master branch and get latest if other developer push their feature branch to master

> git checkout master
>
> git pull

2. Change to featurebranch and merge master to featurebranch if someone pushed their changes to master while you work on featurebranch, so that you may get conflicts to solve

> git checkout hotfix
>
> git merge --no-ff origin master

3. Merge featurebranch to master

> git checkout master
>
> git merge --no-ff origin featurebranch